# Writing a string to an Excel worksheet with Python and Pandas?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

So I have the below and I want to store a dataframe and a string in separate worksheets. What function would I use for the string? to_excel only works with a dataframe so I'm stuck...

```
text = "abcdef"

df = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}

with pd.ExcelWriter('file.xlsx') as write:
 df.to_excelwriter(write, sheet_name = "sheet1")
 text???? #Something to do with .write from xlswriter? Also want to name the worksheet with "sheet9" for example
```

Comment: You need to use an excel library if you want to write to excel. Pandas deals with dataframes and happens to have a wrapper to conveniently export to excel.

Comment: Any suggestions on what to use instead?

Comment: I've used `xlsxwriter` for this kind of job.